VBA 3 variables , if then else help needed
at first i had 2 variables, if in column K is "OUT" fill data from I to F
2nd variable was if in column K is "PAC" fill data from H to E and it work like a charm.
Now i need to add third variable if in column J is fixed value "x" populate data from G to D but in the same time first 2 rules populate columns E and F which i want to be blank if there is value in J, how to rule out other 2 rules if there is value in column K
Only one data should be present in D,E;F in same time
How to achieve that?
I am total noob and self learner within VBA and i hope you will understand what i want :)
            If Worksheets(1).Cells(Row, "J").Value = "x" Then
            Range("Leap2B!D" & Leap2BRow).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(Row, "G").Value
            End If

                                    
            If Worksheets(1).Cells(Row, "K").Value = "OUT" Then
            Range("Leap2B!F" & Leap2BRow).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(Row, "I").Value
            End If

    
            If Worksheets(1).Cells(Row, "K").Value = "PAC" Then
            Range("Leap2B!E" & Leap2BRow).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(Row, "H").Value
            End If

Thanks everyone.

Look into ELSEIF

Yeah i checked and googled ELSEIF but still cant figure out how to make it work :( but thanx for tip.
